# Can corrupted items (gems) be upgraded with GCP or other quality-increasing currency?

Tags: path-of-exile

It is known that corrupted items cannot be altered with currency items. Does this apply also to quality?

Can I upgrade quality of a corrupted gem with a GCP?
Can I upgrade quality of a weapon with a whetstone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you cannot alter a Corrupted Gem with GCP (Gemcutter's Prism).**
Because an item's quality is an alternation that boosts the damage/armor/etc. of an item, it cannot be used on Corrupted Gems.